# NGINX Index 404 Not Found

Tags: php, nginx, ghost

I've just installed a Ghost Blog on a new server running NGINX. The Ghost config.json file is pointing at the correct directory /blog and the blog loads fine when I visit it.

What isn't working is when I remove /blog from the URL, I get taken to a 404 page. I've checked my sites-enabled file, which looks like this:

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;

server_name *********;
root /var/www/ghost/system/nginx-root;

location ^~ /blog {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_pass http://*********:2368;
    proxy_redirect off;
}

location ~ /.well-known {
    allow all;
}

client_max_body_size 50m;
```

But I'm not entirely sure what I need to change to not get the 404 error. I have an example .php file which should be loading but isn't.

I've always used the Digital Ocean One-Click Ghost app but I wanted to use the Ghost CLI this time round. I have a feeling I've missed something though.

Comment: create index.php on `/var/www/ghost/system/nginx-root`

Comment: Tried that, but it now gives me a 403 Forbidden error.

Comment: Nevermind - I missed the part about a PHP file...

Answer (score 0):

the following may remove some of your restrictions but it will work

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    server_name _;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/thedomain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/thedomain.com/privkey.pem;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/thedomain.access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/thedomain.error.log;

    root            /var/www/thedomain;

    index           index.html;

    gzip on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types text/css text/javascript text/xml text/plain application/javascript application/x-javascript application/json;

    location / {
        try_files   $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

You need to make sure all the ssl files are there and permissioned for access by www-data.

If you need to run certbot for the first time, just but the 443 code in an 80 block without the ssl statements

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your code but got the following error when I went to start NGINX - "Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details."

Comment: @Jayp ok, let me set it up, one sec

Comment: Sure, no worries

Comment: @Jayp ok, I got it running, you need to make sure the ssl files are there and are permissioned for access by www-data (I think). good luck

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it!

Answer (score 0):

The nginx configuration you've posted only deals with Ghost.

You've setup a server responding on port 80, set the root to Ghost's nginx-root, and created 2 location blocks. One is for `/blog/` and serves Ghost, the second `.well-known` block is for handling generation of SSL certificates with letsencrypt.

I'm not an expert at configuring nginx for PHP, but [this guide from Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-install-ghost-and-wordpress-in-the-same-droplet) and [this stackoverflow question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134666/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-enable-php-on-nginx) covers a lot of the details.

I think you have a couple of options:

1. Set the index to be index.php
2. Add a new location block for `/` which serves php files
3. Add a block to handle all php files

I believe adding a new location block like this, will mean any .php files you have will always be called if the path in the URL matches.

```
location ~ \.php$ {
      try_files $uri =404;
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      include fastcgi_params;
}
```

But the value of fastcgi_pass will depend on how you have PHP setup on your system.

With this, going to /index.php should work.

Setting `index: index.php` will mean that `/` maps to `/index.php` I'm not sure if that will interfere with Ghost, if it does, you'd need a specific `location / {}` block instead of the index being set.